# Seperate log path and dump path in expdp

Tags: oracle12c, expdp

I have to run multiple exports in one of the Oracle 12c databases for which I am using PAR files. Now I want to put the dump file and the log file in separate paths while using expdp. 
Please guide me on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DIRECTORY` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D7F1C0E8-E3CF-495E-9596-E08AEE36BB6B)

> Specifies the default location to which Export can write the dump file set and the log file.

The [`DUMPFILE` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-A6300021-419F-4C1D-AFF1-38FE1123326B) and [`LOGFILE` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-3536160E-68D8-4455-8A64-F1A44032EABD) each allow that default to overridden, by supplying an optional directory name:

> `DUMPFILE=[directory_object:]file_name [, ...]`
>
> `LOGFILE=[directory_object:]file_name`

So your parameter file needs to include those overriding directory names in the relevant parameters. Note that they still have to directory *objects*, defined in the database and which you have privileges against; you can't supply native operating systems paths directly in any of those parameters.